# Django - Get data from another model in Detailview

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get objects from two models using DetailView.
First I set urls.py:

```
url(r'^page/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page-detail'),
```

I've created a model:

```
class PageContainer(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pages(models.Model):
    pageContainer = models.ForeignKey(PageContainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uniq = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pages"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

and the DetailView:

```
class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Pages

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PageDetailView, self).get_queryset().filter(site_id=4)
```

> I've set  .filter(site_id=4) because there are some pages with some
>   slug (home) and I want to retrieve the page only for selected site
>   (site_id=4 in my db).

Now, in my template, I can use:

```
{{ object.name }}
```

to retrieve the page name but, I need to get some info of another table, in this view.
How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you said what the info from the other table is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [add extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) by overriding `get_context_data`.

```
class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PageDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add extra context from another model
        context['other_model'] = OtherModel.objects.get(...)
        return context
```